# How do I produce a BarLegend with the default coloring of a ContourPlot, using Legended?

Tags: plotting, color, legending

I have a series of `ContourPlot`s that I want to compare in a `GraphicsRow` environment. I want to add a single legend for all three plots. Also, I really like the standard color scheme of the `ContourPlot`.

> *How can I use the standard `ColorFunction` from `ContourPlot` in a different `Graphics` object?*

I did not find the `ColorFunction` that `ContourPlot` uses inside `ColorData["Gradients"]`.

A minimal working example would be this line

```
Legended[ContourPlot[x y, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}],
         Placed[BarLegend[{Automatic, {0, 1}}, LegendLayout -> "Row"], Below]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

where I'm done when the `BarLegend` shows the same colors as the `ContourPlot`.

Comment: For reference: ``Sort[DataPaclets`ColorDataDump`gradientSchemeNames]`` gives a complete list of all the available gradients.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
Legended[ContourPlot[x y, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}],
 Placed[BarLegend[{ColorData["M10DefaultDensityGradient"], {0, 1}}, 
   LegendLayout -> "Row"], Below]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I found the name of the color scheme by evaluating

```
plot = ContourPlot[x y, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

and looking at the expression of the result. As `Legended` accepts two arguments with the second being the legend, this can be easily done by running

```
plot[[2]] // InputForm
```

Comment: Added some code to round out the example.

Comment: Thanks, the edits definitely improve the answer.

Comment: The answer already got a +1 from me. I was just rounding it out.

Comment: Thanks for figuring this out! +1

Answer (score 1):

Create your plots with the option `PlotLegends -> Automatic`:

```
threecontourplots = {plot1, plot2, plot3} = 
 ContourPlot[#, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, PlotLegends -> Automatic, ImageSize -> 300] & /@ 
   {x y, x + y , x};
```

For a legended plot object `plot`, you can use `Part` to extract the main plot (`plot1[[1]]`) and the legend  (`plot1[[2,1]]`).

```
threecontourplots[[1, 2, 1]]
```

[image]

You can use the extracted parts with `Row`, `GraphicsRow`, `Grid`,`GraphicsGrid` as well as with `Legended`:

```
Row[Append[threecontourplots[[1, 2, 1]]]@threecontourplots[[All, 1]], 
 Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

```
Legended[Row[threecontourplots[[All, 1]], Spacer[10]], 
 Placed[threecontourplots[[1, 2, 1]], Right]]
```

[image]

If you use a non-default color function in `ContourPlot` (say, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"`) no modification will be needed:

`[image]